# Incrementing The Index getting error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xcode7

I am using the `core data` in my Project. I have an option to add the car in my App and i am displaying that added cars inside the `tableView` fortunatly i have added 3 rows. When I open my App I am calling the Service in that I am getting totally 45 data. I have to compare that 3 `tableview` data with the 45 data.

Here I created an `NSInteger` totalCars variable.

Here is my code:

```
totCars = self.carSelectionManager.totalCars;
```

and I am getting the first row data by passing the “index = 0” statically.

```
Car *car = [self.carSelectionManager carAtIndex:0];
[self.service getMakesForYear:car.year]; // with the help of first row data I am calling the service data.
```

I am getting the first row data. Similarly I want the remaining second and third row data too. But I am unable to write the logic for that can anyone help to solve this issue.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please try :

```
for ( Car * car in self.carSelectionManager){
    [self.service getMakesForYear:car.year];
}
```

Or you can try this:

```
if (carSelectionManager){
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < [self.carSelectionManager count];i++){
    Car *car = [self.carSelectionManager carAtIndex:0];
    [self.service getMakesForYear:car.year];
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting this warning "Collection expression type 'CarSelectionManager *' may not respond to 'countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:'". CarSelectionManager is a Class.

Comment: of add function to count number of cars , and class it
 means : when added new car increment counter , and return in count function .